# Address of Delphi label

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm working on a simple PIC18 MCPU mnemonic simulation in Delphi pascal. And yes, I intend to use Delphi IDE.
I'm able to simulate any asm instruction, but it stops at labels.
In some cases I need to know the address of Delphi label.
Is there any possibility to cast label in to pointer variable?

As in my example?

```
procedure addlw(const n:byte); //emulation of mcpu addlw instruction
begin
  Carry := (wreg + n) >= 256;
  wreg := wreg + n;
  Zero := wreg = 0;
  inc(CpuCycles);
end;

procedure bnc(p: pointer ); //emulation of mcpu bnc instruction
asm
  inc   CpuCycles
  cmp   byte ptr Carry, 0
  jnz   @exit
  pop   eax     //restore return addres from stack
  jmp   p
@exit:
end;
```

//EMULATION OF MCPU ASM CODE

```
procedure Test;
label
  Top;
var
  p: pointer;
begin
//
Top:
  addlw(5);  //emulated  mcpu addlw instruction
  bnc(Top);  //emulated  mcpu bnc branch if not carry instruction
//
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand this. Why do you need to obtain the address of a label from inside the same routine?

Comment: It seems the address of the label is the address of the instruction that follows it. I don't think the compiler keeps a reference to it, it puts a JMP while producing the code and that's all.

Comment: @David Heffernan: to emulate goto asm intructions.

Comment: @Sertac, exactly! That's more answer than a comment... Labels are just *design time*, at compile time they are translated to the instruction addresses with no reference, just a constant address.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I must find different solution...

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by emulate goto asm instruction. Emulate where?

Comment: @ David Heffernan: I wont to do for any emulated asm instruction own pascal procedure. Like: `addlw(param);` but I must inside this procedure alco count emulated cpu cycles and sets some emulated cpu flags. So I need the address of label. I know that I can use address of label inside `asm ... end` but I will lost the visibility of emulated code.

Comment: @David Heffernan: OK, I have added more detailed code example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't interact with labels that way. Since you're *emulating* everything else, you may as well emulate assembler labels, too, instead of trying to force Delphi labels to do something they're not designed for.

Suppose you could use code like this instead of the "assembler" code you wrote (without worrying for now exactly how to implement it):

```
procedure Test;
var
  Top: TAsmLabel;
begin
//
DefineLabel(Top);
  addlw(5);  //emulated  mcpu addlw instruction
  bnc(Top);  //emulated  mcpu bnc branch if not carry instruction
//
end;
```

The syntax looks similar enough, I think. Upon running that code, you'll want `Top` to refer to the next instruction, which is the one that calls `addlw`.

Inside the hypothetical function `DefineLabel`, that address corresponds to the *return address*, so write `DefineLabel` to store its return address in the given parameter:

```
type
  TAsmLabel = Pointer;

procedure DefineLabel(out Result: TAsmLabel);
asm
  mov ecx, [esp]  // copy return address
  mov [eax], ecx  // store result
end;
```

---

Beware that this code corrupts the stack. Your `bcn` function leaves its return address on the stack, so when the carry flag eventually gets set, you've left a trail of previous return addresses on the stack. If you don't get a stack overflow first, you'll hit strange results when you get to the end of the containing function. It will try to return, but instead of going to the caller, it will find `bnc`'s return address instead, and jump back into the middle of your code. And that's all assuming there aren't any other stack-relative references in the code. If there are, then even *calling* `bnc(Top)` might give problems because the relative position of `Top` will have changed, and you'll end up reading the wrong value off the stack.

Comment: Yes, It looks likes the only way! But the problems becomes if we wont to have label below of the calling procedure. So, everithing what I can remember is to initiate labels at first procedure call, so to add in all procedures init flag wich will skip the real code execution at first call and only initiate labels.